# Importing graphic data into text file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, writetofile, reply, ginput

I am trying to create a program in MATLAB by which I can click on an image (using the input command) and MATLAB outputs a graphic marker on the image, and stores the data to a text file.
The motivation for this comes the Major League Baseball Gameday App, as I want to use it for a similar purpose, but on the input rather than the receiving end. I have created a code which takes an image and outputs a graphic marker at the points clicked. However, I need to improve the code by (hopefully) color coding each marker according to a manual input (maybe using the reply function?) and also numbering each marker. Also, I would like it to output the reply, location, and number to a text file which can be saved for later. 
The code I have is below (with comments explaining what is missing), any help is appreciated.

```
img=imread('Path/Filename.png');
image(img);
title('Pitching')

ginput
%ask for reply of text between each click
M=[ans];
N=length(M);

hold on

for i=1:N
    plot(M(i,1),M(i,2),'o','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',25); 
    %make FaceColor coded according to reply from click
    %number each click
    %write data to text file


end
```

Comment: why is this tagged google-maps?

Comment: sorry, fixed. I think it was just suggested.